# How to connect to Django Database from external javascript file?

Tags: javascript, html, database

I have to create a widget in **pure javascript**, **html** and **css** for an application existing.

I looked on the internet for tutorials but I couldn't find anything.

**My problem**: I would like to connect to the database/API knowing that the application is coded in **Django/Angular 8**.

Yes indeed I will use fetch to retrieve my data.
Here is my code:

```
const url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/services';

fetch(url)
    .then(res => {
        res.json()
    })
    .then(data => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
    });
```

I think i have found what i want [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/api-clients/#javascript-client-library)

But i don't understand this line:

```
{% load static %}
<script src="{% static 'rest_framework/js/coreapi-0.1.1.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% url 'api-docs:schema-js' %}"></script>
```

My widget is encoded outside my django application, so i can't use '{% %}'.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

By `connect`, do you mean communicate with a rest api?
If so then you should be ale to use [window.fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

The linked MDN article provides examples on how you would be able to do this.

Comment: I tried to connect to the API with fetch but an error message appears

Comment: What error message do you see?
Please update your question with the error message you get from fetch.

Comment: Yes i have edited my question. I would like to connect to Django database.